# priorities for attached events

Tags: events, zend-framework2

From [Doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html) priority argument for event manager are to way to influence order of events execution. In my module I attach postProcess

```
    /** @var \Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager $moduleManager */
    $moduleManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('modulemanager');
    /** @var \Zend\EventManager\SharedEventManager $sharedEvents */
    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $sharedEvents->attach(
        'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController',
        MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'postProcess'),
        1
    );
```

and it works fine i.e. for getList action in my controller. But is not triggered in options action. Any value greater than 1 makes the postProcess to trigger.

So my question is: as from documentation - priority should influence order of events. But in this particular case - it influences if it's triggered at all. Why is that? Is it some kind of a bug?

Comment: The dispatch event will be short circuited if a `Response` instance is returned, in those circumstances no other listeners are visited. It sounds like that's what you have happening. As to why, that's hard to diagnose without knowing what other listeners you might have attached to that event, or the type of data your controller actions are returning.

Comment: My controllers are returning arrays, then postProcess makes json. There are no other events attached by me (but while debugging I've noticed some Zends out of the box events). My shot is (from what you've said): since OPTIONS should not respond with body, but only headers - some event before that returns `Response` and all other events are terminated (?)